# Postgres on Heroku logs getting flooded with alphanumeric characters

Tags: postgresql, heroku, logging

We've recently experienced a flooding of logs on Heroku Postgres, alongside with major performance degradation in our app. Thousands of messages like the following were logged with no clear indication of the cause.

I was wondering if a background process (like VACUUM) could generate such a huge influx of messages, or if this might be something specific to Heroku. Appreciate any help in identifying possible origins.

Log lines contain only (seemingly) hex codes (redacted parts of it for brevity and security). Unfortunately I'm unable to see the value of `log_line_prefix` on Heroku.

```
02/12/2022 10:59:58.000 am
[BLUE] [25-27464] 632d303934312d346539652d6163934312d346539652d616331352d223a7b227374726174656779223a224b525f4f4e4c59222c226368696c644f626a65637469766557656967687473223a6e756c6c2c226b6579526573756c7457656967687473223a6e756c6c7d2c226b6579526573756c744869657261726368794e6f646573223a5b7b226964223a2231643231663765392d616534302d346136312d613265322d346338336466353466316162222c22737461747573223a22414354495645222c2263616c63756c617465644d657472696356616c7565436f6e66

02/12/2022 10:59:58.000 am
[BLUE] [25-27466] 352d643032362d346436372d3933373223a39362e38383038323734794e6f646573223a5b7b226964223a2265666331666361372d353430642d343732632d383162642d656330666430386337323631222c22737461747573223a22414354495645222c2263616c63756c617465644d657472696356616c7565436f6e66696775726174696f6e223a6e756c6c2c226d657472696356616c7565223a31353431392e302c22616363756d756c6174656456616c7565223a6e756c6c2c22616363756d756c61746564476f616c223a37353335352e32383535333035343336

02/12/2022 10:59:58.000 am
[BLUE] [25-27471] 756c6c2c2267726964457870726573331227d5d7d2c226162353833657373223a6e756c6c2c22737461747573223a22414354495645222c2270726f6772657373436f6e66696775726174696f6e223a7b227374726174656779223a224b525f4f4e4c59222c226368696c644f626a65637469766557656967687473223a6e756c6c2c226b6579526573756c7457656967687473223a6e756c6c7d2c226b6579526573756c744869657261726368794e6f646573223a5b7b226964223a2231623266383838632d353836322d346462382d613934312d3663636135313364
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: What is log_line_prefix set to? Can you change it to be more useful, like including times and IP addresses?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to see the value of log_line_prefix on Heroku. What I found strange was that there were hundreds of thousands of lines containing only those (seemingly) hex codes. @Chris will include text as soon as stack overflow allows me.